# Unity tilemap issue with generated tiles and collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue in Unity with tilemaps. I'd like to create tiles dynamically in code and destroy them in code. However when I do this, the tile isn't recognised as a valid tile.

The gif below shows a block of tiles created by code and a line of blocks created by the tile palette. When running the game the line of tiles is recognised in the inspector window as having a tile and a sprite. The generated tiles do not.

This is the code I use to generate the tiles. I pass in Tile2 as a Tile.

```
for (int row = minRowNum; row <= maxRowNum; row++)
{
    for (int col = minColNum; col >= maxColNum; col--)
    {
        var position = new Vector3Int(row, col, 1);

        Bricks.SetTile(position, Tile2);
        Bricks.SetTileFlags(position, TileFlags.None);
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to destroy the tile:

```
var position = tilemap.WorldToCell(hitPosition);

var brick = tilemap.GetTile(position);

tilemap.SetTile(position, null);
```

This setup works fine if I just paint the tiles onto the grid. The ball collides and the tile is removed but not so with the generated tiles. The GetTile function will return null.

I think I'm either missing a step or maybe using the wrong tools to generate my bricks. Previously I've had the tiles (bricks) as prefabs and generated my own grid which works fine but the tilemap looked like a nicer solution.

Here is the full code to generate my grid: https://pastebin.com/0DvufLmV

Here is the full code to detect collisions: https://pastebin.com/FviZKb7Q

Github: https://github.com/Tikeb/AnotherBreakoutTest

[image: Inspector window]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your brick class, this is very hard to debug. But there are some structural recommendations that I think will ultimately solve your problem.

One major problem I'm seeing with your code (as far as the code you've given us) is that you don't have a CreateBrick() method. So lets think of your tilemap class the place where we store our references to our tile objects. Lets also assume you have a tile prefab gameobject.

The way you would setup your tilemap class would be:

```
    public GameObject TilePrefab;
    public List<Tile> Tiles;
    public void CreateTile(Vector3 position)
    {
        var tileGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate(TilePrefab);
        TilePrefab.transom.position = position;
        //probably set as a child too
        Tiles.Add(tileGameObject.GetComponent<Tile>());
    }

    public void InitializeStartingTiles()
    {
        for (int row = minRowNum; row <= maxRowNum; row++)
        {
            for (int col = minColNum; col >= maxColNum; col--)
            {
                var position = new Vector3Int(row, col, 1);

                CreateTile(position);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now that we have a method for generating new tiles, we ONLY use that method. Tiles should never be created in any other way. This ensures that every tiles is created properly. Another important design point here is that the tilemap is the only object that can create tiles, so to create a tile, you will need a reference to the tilemap.

Now, your problem is that some of your tiles are being created differently to others. More specifically, some have sprites, others don't. This is likely due to using a different Tile creation process in your initial grid setup, to when you add them during runtime. If you stick to the structure I described, you will ensure that all your tiles are created the same.

Comment: Sorry, never know how much info to give. I've updated the question with links to the full code for generating my tilemap and the mechanism for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

With procedurally generated tiles you need to force the tilemap collider to update it's collider information before collisions can be detected.

```
TilemapCollider2D collider = tilemap.GetComponent<TilemapCollider2D>();
if (collider.hasTilemapChanges)
{
    tilemap.GetComponent<TilemapCollider2D>().ProcessTilemapChanges();
}
```